# opencv kmeans function with pre-selection

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In openCV, with the kmeans is it possible to pre-define some groups?

```
kmeans(input,10,label,cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 1, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,centroid);
```

For example, the "input" array is a 10 rows mat, and I already know, row 1, 7, 10 belongs to one group, is it possible to put this info into kmeans before it groups these data into 5 clusters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define user defined starting labels. 
Use cv::KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS instead of cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS
and in labels matrix that you insert to the function (the third argument) insert a label matrix with your initial labeling i.e the rows 1,7,10 will have the same starting label.